# Cómo traer data con modelos relacionados?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hola Amigos que tal? tengo la siguiente estructura de tablas en mi api de Laravel

```
Escuela      Escuela_Nivel        Nivel            jornada
- id          -id                  - id             - id
- nombre      - escuela_id         - nombre         - nombre
              - nivel_id           - jornada_id
```

con eloquent puedo traer todos los niveles asociados a cada escuela de la siguinete forma

```
public static function EscuelaNivel($id)
{
    $escuela= Escuela::findOrFail($id);
    $niveles = $escuela->niveles;
      
    return ['niveles'  => $niveles];
   
}
```

La consulta anterior me arroja de manera correcta todos los niveles asociados a una escuela determinada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase Nivel

```
 public function escuelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Escuela::class, 'escuela_nivel');  
    }

public function jornadas(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Jornadas::class,'jornada')
            ->withPivot('id');
    }
```

Clase Escuela

```
public function niveles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Nivel::class,'escuela_nivel'); 
}
```

Clase Jornada

```
public function niveles(){
    return $this->hasMany(Nivel::class, 'niveles', 'id');
}
```

mi pregunta es, como puedo traer las jornadas a las que pertenecen los niveles que he conseguido con la consulta `$niveles = $escuela->niveles;` ?

Gracias por responder, saludos.

Comment: Puedes hacer un join desde la tabla niveles a jornada, donde te traiga el nombre donde la comparación sea la jornada_id de Nivel, y el id de la tabla jornada.

Comment: Hola que tal ?... he realizado un join entre las 2 tablas, me trae el resultado repetido 10 veces, lo que necesito que me traiga es que al momento de que el usuario seleccione 1 escuela, me muestre todos los niveles que tiene esa escuela, eso lo puedo conseguir sin problemas con la consulta $niveles = $escuela->niveles; luego de eso quiero traer las jornadas a la que pertenecen esos niveles, pj: si la escuela tiene 3 nivel sala cuna de la jornada normal, quiero que me traiga solo el nombre individual "jornada normal" no repetido 3 veces.